# React native firebase email verification

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

Is there any feature in firebase to check if the verification email sent to a user already? I can check validation but I gotta check if the verification email sent to a user already to know if I need to send it again.

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the promise object you have the boolean value "emailVerified".